Heat Pump head making noise
I moved into a house this Spring that has a Samsung Heat Pump. It has 1 outdoor unit and 3 indoor heads.
The units have been functioning fine, but recently one of them started making an unusual noise.
I don't know the best way to describe it other than a bit of a whirring or maybe rattling. When Googling, I often find that rattling could be from loose parts, but it's not that kind of metal on metal/plastic of something banging around, and is instead just a consistent noise louder than it usually makes.
The other two heads do not make this noise.
Does anyone have any suggestions on where I could start for troubleshooting this issue? I'm pretty new to heat pumps but have cleaned the filter on the top of all 3 units and confirmed that the filter on the one making the noise doesn't seem to be messy.

It sounds like you have mini-split units,  Diagnosing a noise online is like eating a virtual meal. One can only imagine what it is like.  Just a guess is that something is hitting the fan. How to get at it I have no idea. Perhaps finding the model number of the wall unit can result in an idea of how to axcess that part.
